# Java guessing letter game

Tags: java

Hi im currently creating a guessing letter game! So far i have made it so you guess between the numbers 1 and 26 using the java.util.random class. However this random number should be converted into the corresponding number within the alphabet! ie a=1 etc..This is where my problem is i dont know how to convert this randomly generated number into a letter! This needs to be related to the integer as i have to able to tell the user if they are above the letter in the alphabet or to low based on the guess they entered! One more thing is that the users guess will be a letter also! Below is my code! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
{

    Random rand = new Random(); //This is were the computer selects the Target

    int guess;
    int numGuesses = 0;
    int Target;
    String userName;
    String playagain;
    boolean play = true;
    int session = 0;
    int sessions = 0;
    int bestScore = 0;

    Scanner consoleIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Hello! Please enter your name:\n"); //This is were the user enters his/her name
    userName= name.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Hello "+ userName + " :) Welcome to the game!\n");


    while (play = true)
    {
        session++;
        Target = rand.nextInt(26) + 1;
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 26? You will have 5 attempts to guess the correct number"); //This is where the computer asks the user to guess the number and how many guesses they will have

        do {
            guess = consoleIn.nextInt();
            numGuesses++;

            if (guess > 26)
                System.out.println("Error! Above MAXIMUM range");
            else if (guess <= 0)
                System.out.println("Error! Below MINIMUM range");
            else if (guess > Target)
                System.out.println("Sorry! Your guess was too high! :)"); //This is to help the player get to the answer 
            else if (guess < Target)
                System.out.println("Sorry! Your guess was too low! :)"); //This is to help the player get to the answer 
           }        
            while(guess != Target && numGuesses <5);

            if(guess == Target) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations "+  userName + ", it took you "+ numGuesses +" attempts to guess correctly!"); //This tells the player that they got the correct answer and how many attempts it took
                sessions++;
                    }

            else 
            {
            System.out.println("Sorry "+ userName + ", You've used up all of your guesses! The correct answer was "+ Target + "!");  //This tells the player that they failed to find the number and then tells them what the correct answer  
            }
            {
            Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Would you like another GO "+ userName +"? [Y/N]");//This asks the player if they would like to play again
            playagain = answer.nextLine();
           if(playagain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))//This is what happens if the player opts to play again
            {
            play = true;
            numGuesses = 0;

            } else if(playagain.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))//This is what happens if the player opts to exit the game
            {
                play = false;
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing "+ userName +"! :) Please come back soon!");
                System.out.println("You had  "+ session +" Goes");
                System.out.println("The number of times you guessed correctly: "+ sessions +"");
                break;
            }

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (play = true)` is doing assignment

Comment: Yes it is for an assignment, Im not asking for an answer i just want pointers, as i have tried various methods! Which yes have made a random letter but they then stopped allowing the feedback in relation high or low

Comment: No, `play = true` is doing assignment. what you want is `play == true`

Comment: @Slynch771 basically *ScaryWombat* is trying to say that you are setting play as true, and not checking if it is true, unless you use "==", note that for objects that would be *.equals()*

Comment: The `play` variable is unnecessary anyway. It is `true` during the whole game, and when it is set to `false` the loop is exited with `break` afterwards. This means that `while (true)` would have done the same job.

Comment: @Aloso well true, as long as it doesn't get nested in something else, it is completely useless ye

Comment: Oh right apoligies haha xD Sorry that shows how new i am to coding!

Comment: There's nothing to excuse for. I also wanted to mention that `play == true` is more complex than necessary. `play == true` is equivalent with `play`. Forthermore, instead of writing `play == false`, one can simply write `!play`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Random random = new Random();
 char c = (char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

This maps (0 to 25 ) to ('a' to 'z')

Comment: Hi Tom! When doing this i want the user to be able to guess a letter, which is then converted to an integer after they enter it! Will this still work?

Comment: @Slynch771 read the solution, and try to understand it ... but he is casting a char form an int, hints ascii, and static conversion rates

Comment: @Mikenno Thanks dude! Okay i will research it